# Filter linq query in entity framework core, many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using the ASP Net Core 2.
I have a test model:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public ICollection<PlayerTeam> PlayerTeams { get; set; }
    public Player()
    {
        PlayerTeams = new List<PlayerTeam>();
    }
}
public class PlayerTeam
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // название команды
  //  [IgnoreDataMember]
    public ICollection<PlayerTeam> PlayerTeams { get; set; }
    public Team()
    {
        PlayerTeams = new List<PlayerTeam>();
    }
}
```

this is my DBcontext:

```
public class FootbollContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player>  Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public FootbollContext(DbContextOptions<FootbollContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           

        modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerTeam>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.TeamId, t.PlayerId });

    }
}
```

I have a query in my controller:

```
FootbollContext db;
var teams = db.Teams.Select(team => new { 
    TeamName = team.Name,
    PlayersOlder20 = team.PlayerTeams.Where(pt => pt.Player.Age > 20).Select(s => s.Player)
});
```

and it works fine, but I want to use the `Include()`/`ThenInclude()` methods for this query, and I want to get the same equal results ie.

```
var teams = db.Teams.Include(p => p.PlayerTeams).ThenInclude(d => d.Player)
```

but I don't want to load all data! and I don't know how I can filter results by property "Players age (> 20)" in the relative table (not in the selectable!!) in one SQL Query.

Comment: Include is not selective.

Comment: Look at [model-level query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/).